# TS - assign value from a callback function using return

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im getting data of class `People` array with each person having attendance list as `Observable<any[]>`.

```
// Class person
class Person {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   attendance: Observable<any[]>; // An Observable array
}


// People array (I only use array for simplicity sake)
// NOTE: Every person has a list of attendance
people = Person[] = this.someService.getPeople();
```

Now I'm validating if some of the people may had 0 length of attendance assuming that `attendance: Observable<any[]>` is always an empty array `[]` if nothing is found, return false otherwise true to `validateAttendance()`.

```
validateAttendance(): boolean {

    // Loop to each person and get attendance list.
    people.forEach(p => {
       // Get the list using a callback function.
       const func = (callback: (data) => void) => {
            // Get attendance using subscribe() method
            p.attendance.subscribe(list => {    
                callback(list);
            });
        }

       // An attempt to get the list from a callback function
       // Failed because return is undefined.
       const result = func(res => {
           console.log(res); // Got list of attendance of a given person.
           return res;
       });

       if (result.length <= 0) {
           alert(`${p.name} has no attendance, must be a lazy one please check.`);
           return false;
       }
    });

    return true;
}
```

In order to do that i attempted to create a callback function inside the `validateAttendance()` method and return the attendance list from it. **HOWEVER the result variable is undefined!**

It is possible to return a value from a callback function this way?

Comment: if ANY of the code inside `validateAttendance` is asynchronous (e.g. ` p.attendance.subscribe` looks asynchronous) then there is no way to return the result synchronously, no matter how much funky callbackery you add

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks i should really change approach, but i really thought we can return a value from `func(list => { return list });`

Comment: "return a value" ... sure, but what does `func` return? `undefined` ...

Comment: `func` was able to give me the list but when returning a value back to func yea it is `undefined`, sort of playing the flow haha

Comment: because asynchronous code remains asynchronous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Saravana the question is different, when you look at my code i created it from that source. and it doesn't solve my problem thanks to `@JaromandaX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. It is asynchronous, so the function needs to be async too (using `Promise`)
2. `func()` does not return a value, so the `result` will always be undefined.
3. You have `alert()` deep in your code. Are you going to pop up for each person with no attendance? It is better to separate logic and UI.

I have modified your code to the following:

```
function validateAttendance(people): Promise<boolean> {
  return getPeopleWithNoAttendance(people)
    .then(peopleWithNoAttendance => {
      if (peopleWithNoAttendance.length > 0) {
        // or loop though them
        alert(`${peopleWithNoAttendance[0].name} has no attendance, must be a lazy one please check.`);
        return false
      }
      return true
    })
}

function getPeopleWithNoAttendance(people) {
  return Promise.all(people.map(person => {
    return new Promise(r => {
      person.attendance.subscribe(r)
    }).then(attendance => {
      return attendance.length <= 0 ? person : undefined
    })
  })).then(listOfPeopleOrUndefined => {
    const listOfPeople = listOfPeopeleOrUndefined.filter(p => p)
    return listOfPeople
  })
}
```

Also changed is having the `people` variable passed in. If this is a method in a class, feel free to change that.

Comment: good this is i really change my method to return Promise<boolean>, it does great

Comment: `return new Promise(r => {
      person.attendance.subscribe(r)
    }` could be written more succintly as just `return person.attendance.toPromise()`